# Detect when all ASP.NET-generated Javascript has run

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, page-lifecycle, collapsiblepanelextender

I currently have a page that contains a RadTreeView.  On each node of the RadTreeView is an ASP.NET Ajax CollapsiblePanelExtender.  In the code-behind I have certain panels expanded and certain panels collapsed based on some business logic.  Is there a way to detect when ALL ASP.NET-generated Javascript (collapsing/expanding of CollapsiblePanelExtender) has run?  I need to act on the elements but NOT until all expanding and collapsing has taken place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CollapsiblePanelExtender initializes by using [Sys.Application.init Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397532.aspx).  If you used the [Sys.Application.load Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829.aspx), you could guarantee your code ran after theirs.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I've been trying to find a solution for quite some time and this was the only one that worked!